# How to create a product mock-up template in GIMP (or another app)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gimp, mockup

I'm trying to create product mockups for snowmobile vinyl wraps, and need a template to start from. Unfortunately nowhere I've looked has had templates ready. YelloImages said they could make some, but it may take 8-10 months.

How difficult is it to create my own? How would you do it?

Is it possible to project a pattern/design onto a non-flat surface?

Finished template would hopefully look something close to this (but for a snowmobile): https://yellowimages.com/stock/kawasaki-kx-250f-mockup-right-side-view-11611/

Finished mockup hopefully something like this: https://www.arcticfxgraphics.com/v/Arctic_Cat/next-gen-ascender/style/absolute_zero/101377#&slider1=3

Comment: GIMP has no such functionality, except for very basic 3D spheres, cubes, planes or cylinders . It just isn't designed for this kind of work - look instead at doing it in 3D modelling software such as Blender. It's free and Open Source. You'd first have to find or create a 3D model of the bike/snowmobile.  You'd also have to learn about UV mapping to wrap a 2D image to a 3D mesh. If you get stuck there is a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have a look at this Blender tutorial showing how to add decals to a 3D model vehicle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=75&v=3qq994Ugsss